# How to create a .exe with visual studio 2015 that I can run from my desktop

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015

I've written a game using OpenGL, GLFW, C/C++. I use third party libraries like SOIL and irrKlang. I use Microsoft Visual 2015. Both the debug and release version run ok from visual studio. In properties -> C++ -> Code Generation-> Runtime Library I selected /MDd. I did try other settings but the release version wouldn't work with any other. All of my .dll are saved in the release and debug folders. 
However, when I go to my release folder and copy and paste the .exe found there, onto my desktop,it no longer runs. I keep getting a message that says the irrKlang.dll is missing. Could someone please explain how to get a standalone .exe of my game up and running?

Comment: `Wouldn't work with any other` what? PCs?

Comment: Usually the way to go is creating installer which would install all the dependancies, or made sure you have them on your drive, it isn't good idea to put all dependant dlls into exe as there may be a LOT of them.

Answer (score 3):

Two things here. First, the .exe is the executable which contains the entry point of your application. So this is indeed the first piece you need. However, your application is allowed to depend on code that's not linked into it statically, but rather dynamically -- such dynamically linked code is only loaded at runtime. These runtime libraries of code are called DLLs ("dynamically linked libraries").

If your application depends on a DLL, it will [look for that DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#search_order_for_desktop_applications) while it's running. If it doesn't find it, you'll see that message box about a missing DLL. So, you need to copy not only the .exe file, but all the .dlls it depends on (and that they depend on) too. Note that your application links against many default system DLLs, e.g. kernel32, but these don't need to be copied next to the .exe because they're always present in the system search path.

Now, the second part. If you want to run your application on a PC that doesn't have Visual Studio installed, you need to make sure that computer has the C/C++ runtimes that the VS2015 toolchain automatically links against installed. These are not DLLs that you copy by hand; rather, there is a [redistributable installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49984) for them which installs them globally on the PC for all applications. You can ship this with your own installer.

For this to work, you want to be linking with just `/MD` in Release (the debug CRT is for debugging only, and is only installed when Visual Studio is installed -- it's not meant to run outside your PC).

Comment: Or you can also install them in system and look in system directories if they are often used packages (thought its worth adding).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I created a folder on my desktop, and pasted the .exe into that folder, I also pasted the .dll into the same folder. When I run it, the application no longer complains about a missing dll. So that part has been solved! Instead, I now encounter another bug, but thats another question.....

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

"Both the debug and release version run ok from visual studio. In properties -> C++ -> Code Generation-> Runtime Library I selected /MDd. I did try other settings but the release version wouldn't work with any other."

Leads me to believe that maybe you don't have a release version of one of your third party libraries.

/MDd causes your application to use the debug version of the MS runtime, which means that something in your project is being built with or as a debug version.

I use the 'depends.exe' application to see the dependencies of my executables and DLLs.  It used to be provided directly by Microsoft, but now seems to be supported via a third party.  Older SDKs will have it.

http://www.dependencywalker.com/